# Excel 2016 VBA backward compatibility issue to 2013

Tags: excel, vba, backwards-compatibility

I have a simple VBA code, created in Excel 2016, that hides some rows in other sheets based on whether a user inputs "yes/no". Unfortunately, it does not run in Excel 2013.

*The error message is:*

> Run-time error '1004'  Application-defined or object-defined error.

The debug highlight is in row 9 that starts with `If nmdrange`.
Is there any way to make it backward-compatible?

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim nmdrange As Name
    Dim Row As Range

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("screener1")) Is Nothing Then
        'Input data sheet
        With Sheet4
            For Each nmdrange In ThisWorkbook.Names
                If nmdrange.RefersToRange.Parent.Name = .Name Then '***ERROR HERE***
                'Loop over benefits
                .Range(nmdrange.RefersTo).Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = (.Range(nmdrange.RefersTo).Cells(1, 1).Value = "No")
                End If
            Next nmdrange
        End With

        With Sheet5
            For Each nmdrange In ThisWorkbook.Names
                If nmdrange.RefersToRange.Parent.Name = .Name Then 
                'Loop over benefits
                .Range(nmdrange.RefersTo).Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = (.Range(nmdrange.RefersTo).Cells(1, 1).Value = "No")
                End If
            Next nmdrange
            'Hide in summary table
            For Each Row In .Range("sum_b1").Rows
                Row.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = (Row.Rows.Cells(1, 1).Value = "No")
            Next Row
        End With

    End If
End Sub
```

There are two named ranges that refer not to a range but a single cell/value such as:
[image]

Comment: *'it does not run'* is neither a valid error code nor useful error description.

Comment: I can't see anything obvious there.  When you say "it doesn't run" - what does it do instead?

Comment: "Unfortunately, it does not run in Excel 2013" - can you expand on that? Does it error? What's the error? Where does it stop? I can't see anything obvious that wouldn't work on 2016 but maybe you can narrow it down for us.

Comment: Yes, my apologies - will update in a moment.

Comment: Sorry took me a while to add the error. Could this be solved by `Application.EnableEvents = False`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any named ranges that don't refer to a worksheet?
A named range can also refer to a constant, or formula - so it could be called `VAT` and have a flat value of `20%`

When your loop gets to this named range it won't be able to find the parent worksheet as it doesn't have one.

Comment: Yes, there are two named ranges that refer to a single cell/value. You are saying this makes a difference for Excel 2016 and 2013? I'll update the question with a screenshot.

Comment: No, I'm asking if one of the named ranges `Refers to` something like `=20%` rather than `=Sheet1$A$1`.  A screenshot will answer that though (screenshots are blocked where I am at the moment though).

Comment: In that case, no. All named ranges refer to a worksheet.

Comment: Ah, ok.  That's my theory out the window then.  Maybe I should've added the answer as a comment.  I'll have to look at the image when I get home.